# How to load animation from Assets folder?

Tags: android

I m working on a Android Java Plugin for Unity3D.

I my Android Project, I have a class which is not extending Activity, but i m calling a function from unity & sending current activity in it.

```
public class abc{    
  void init(final Activity currActivity, .. and some other params)
  {
    .....
    my code here.//
    .... .
  }    
}
```

I was using

```
currAnimation_StartAd = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(currActivity, R.anim.slide_in_right);
```

to load my animation from **res** folder when i was extending Activity.

Now my Problem is, i can't access **res** folder bcoz **i m no more extending Activity**.
Actually even i m not getting any compile time error on **R.anim.slide_in_right**.
But in runtime, Resource **R.anim.slide_in_right: 0x7f040001** not found..

**Is there any way to load my animations from assets folder.?**

Thankx.

Comment: show me the definition of R.anim.slide_in_right and please confirm your anim folder actually exists...

Comment: "R.anim.slide_in_right: 0x7f040001 not found" maybe caused by the DDMS compile the apk error, try to remove project from eclipse workspace and delete the project's bin directory, then import the the project to Eclipse workspace.

Comment: @JigarPandya. To access **R.anim** i need to extend Activity, which is not m doing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use getApplicationContext() in that case.. change your like code to

```
currAnimation_StartAd =  AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_in_right);
```

and this should work.

or better explained by gautam with currAnimation_StartAd = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(currActivity.getApplicationContext, R.anim.slide_in_right);

Comment: getApplicationContext() need class to extends Activity.. m i right?

Comment: your answer is corrent but it doesn't work for me. Thankx for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to set animation on any view:

```
view.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.push_up_in));
view.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.push_up_out));
```

For this you have to create anim folder under res of project and create xml file as:
**push_up_in:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <translate android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:toYDelta="0" android:duration="300"/>
        <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="300" />
</set>
```

**push_up_out:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <translate android:fromYDelta="0" android:toYDelta="-100%p" android:duration="300"/>
        <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" android:duration="300" />
</set>
```

Comment: You could do this, or set the Animation in the XML layout file, if any

Comment: @Akash.. **this** wont work in my case. i mentioned above, **my class didn't extends Activity**.

Answer (score 0):

You can still get an Context object to access res folder by Application.
Create an application class:

```
public class app extends Application{
    public static Context c;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        c = this;
    }
    @Override
    public void onTerminate() {
        super.onTerminate();
        c = null;
    }
}
```

remember to declare in manifest, too. And now you can have a context everywhere by

```
app.context
```